# I have a 2011 Chevrolet Impala lt. Where is the fuse for the blender actuator?

Tags: heat

In a 2011 Chevrolet Impala, where is the fuse for the blender actuator motor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you mean "blend door actuator" for the HVAC system (controls temperature and/or air direction)?

Comment: I'm assuming that @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, and not that he is talking about making a smoothie.

Comment: Not sure it would have a separate fuse - most likely on the heater fuse.